# PHP Error Handling for error: 1062

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to PHP and hence I am sorry if my query is basic.
I want some assistance on error handling.

The following PHP code (partial only) inserts data to MySQL table. I have done some reading and found that error 1062 & 1586 & 1859 relate to the Message: Duplicate entry '%s' for key %d. But even after putting this in my code, I am unable to get the code to display the error message I gave below instead of displaying Message: Duplicate entry '%s' for key %d

It always only displays Message: Duplicate entry '%s' for key %d though I have put the error handling in.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xx","xx");

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }


    if($_POST['podnd'] > 31 || $_POST['podny'] > date("Y") || $_POST['podnm'] > 12)
    {
        die('Error: Check the Dates entered' . mysql_error());
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['stagn']) != 7)
    {
        die('Error: Check the tag entered. Service Tag is a 7 charecter alphanumeric code'.mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("software_it", $con);

    $sql="INSERT INTO purchaseorders (ServiceTag, PurchaseOrderDate,PurchaseOrderYear,PurchaseOrderMonth) VALUES
        ('$_POST[stagn]','$_POST[podnd]','$_POST[podny]','$_POST[podnm]')";

    if (mysql_errno() == 1062 || mysql_errno() == 1586 || mysql_errno() == 1859 || mysql_errno() == 3026) 
    {
        print('Error: New Tags only. Please use other link for updating existing records' );
    }

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "1 record added";
    mysql_close($con)
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a Primary key in your db and try to insert a value which is already there

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: Why are you checking for errors before running the query? Also look at the `switch` statement as that `if` is out of control.

Comment: Hi @Jens, Yes I know. I am inserting the value already there on purpose.
I want the PHP to display The error message I specified above. Instead of the generic error message it provides.

Comment: tadman, I am new to this so some of them went above my head. :)

PHP is kinda my only way to go coz I am halfway into the project and we are using MySQL. I have installed MySQL using XAMPP which uses PHP.

Comment: @tadman, Not sure what you mean but I pasted the partial query earlier. I have edited it and pasted the whole query. Can you tell me what exactly you are referring to?

Comment: your `mysql_query` comes after your errno check

Comment: Run the query **first**, then check for errors **second**. You're doing this backwards and you're testing against errors from the previous query. Remember, declaring a variable like `$sql` does nothing other than create a string. It's only when you call the `_query` function it's executed and the errors are updated. Also, please, please please stop using `mysql_query`.

Comment: Thanks guys, fixed it :)